# How to optimize join of multiple (large) tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, query-optimization

I am trying to join multiple tables using `LEFT OUTER` in SQL Server. In the sample below, the table on the left is not that big but the table on the right is about 4-5 millions rows and that's just two tables. There are 3 more tables that needs to be join and they are rather huge tables.

```
-- Example of join for 2 tables
SELECT a.id, a.user_name, a.start_timestamp, a.ref1, a.ref2, a.ref3. a.ref4, b.start_timestamp, b.ref1, b.ref2, b.ref3. b.ref4
FROM
(
  SELECT id, user_name, start_timestamp, ref1, ref2, ref3. ref4
  FROM user
  WHERE DATEDIFF(day,[start_timestamp],GETDATE()) between 0 and 7 
) a
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT id, user_name, start_timestamp, ref1, ref2, ref3. ref4
  FROM user_activity
  WHERE DATEDIFF(day,[start_timestamp],GETDATE()) between 0 and 7 

) b
ON a.id = b.id
```

I tried to limit the columns to absolute necessary fields only and taking only the last 7 days but the SQL query is very slow and taking a long time. Is there a way to make to optimize the joins?

Comment: Don't make your server do algebra, it's not good at it: `WHERE DATEDIFF(day,[start_timestamp],GETDATE()) between 0 and 7` should be `WHERE start_timestamp >= DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE()) AND start_timestamp < GETDATE()`. You probably also want indexes on `start_timestamp` with `INCLUDE` columns. Note that subquerying as you have done makes no difference to performance. For better advice please [edit] and add your table and index definitions and share the query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subqueries are not of any help, so I would remove them.

Then, rephrase the date logic to be direct comparisons.  For this, I will assume that there are no future dates.

Finally, add indexes:

```
select . . .
from user u left join
     user_activity ua
     on ua.id = u.id and
        ua.start_timestamp >= dateadd(day, -7, convert(date, getdate()))
where u.start_timestamp >= dateadd(day, -7, convert(date, getdate()))
```

For this query, you want indexes on `user(start_timestamp)` and `user_activity(id, start_timestamp)`.

The filtering condition on the first table goes in the `where` clause.  For the subsequent tables, it goes in the `on` clause.

Note also the use of *meaningful* table aliases rather than arbitrary letters such as `a` and `b`.  This makes the query much easier to follow.